# Open AlertView before calling method

Tags: objective-c, ios4

I'd like to call a method

```
[self someMethod:bar]
```

But how can I open an AlertView before? *someMethoud* should wait for AlterView OK-Button. Do i need to write a complex task manager? Or is there a smart solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

display the alert, and when the user clicks the button, then call your method.

remember to add the delegate to your class

```
@interface YourViewController : UIViewController <UIAlertViewDelegate>
```

code in your controller

```
// display the alert
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Alert" message:@"Message"
                     delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];  
    [alert show];
    [alert release];
}


// UIAlertViewDelegate method - get the click here and take action
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {       
     if (buttonIndex == 0) {
        // ok button pushed
        [self someMethod:bar];
     }
}
```

Comment: delegate should be `self`, not nil ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You would need to implement the delegate method didDismissWithButtonIndex here http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/ipad/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAlertViewDelegate_Protocol/UIAlertViewDelegate/UIAlertViewDelegate.html

The, depending on the button that was tapped, you would call your method.